# Angular - Esperar dato asincrono para usarse en observable

Tags: angular, async, storage

tengo un servicio que funciona bien para usar Local Storage cuyos métodos son asíncronos.

```
import { Inyectable } from '@angular/core'
import { Storage } from '@capacitor/storage'

@Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root',
)}

async getString(key: string): Promise<{ value: any }>{
  return await Storage.get({key});
}
```

Por otro lado, en otro servicio (productos), tengo un servicio que tiene un método para retornar por http:

```
public retornarElemento(uname: any){
    return this.http.post(url, {username: uname })
}
```

Lo que quiero hacer es lo siguiente, pero el valor asíncrono siempre llega tarde:

```
this.storage.getString('uname').then((data: any) => {
 this.uname= data.value
}
this.producto.retornarElemento(this.uname)
```

¿Como puedo hacer para que el valor del local storage llegue primero y espere para ejecutar la sentencia del http?

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Todo el código que dependa del valor obtenido debe estar dentro de la función callback:

```
this.storage.getString('uname').then((data: any) => {
 this.uname= data.value
 this.producto.retornarElemento(this.uname)
}
// todo el código en este punto se ejecutará antes de obtener el dato desde el localstorage
```